# Transforming a checkerboard using Transpose and ReshapeLayers

Tags: list-manipulation, neural-networks

In the paper for [RealNVP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08803.pdf), they introduce a "squeezing" operation that takes a matrix and transforms it to have more channels, according to the following transformation (before and after):

[image]

As you can see, blocks on the checkerboard with 1 block in between them are placed together in the final checkerboard - almost as if we are taking the corners of a 3x3 square that is moved around the checkerboard for each channel. In python, I would implement this as tensorflow.space_to_depth(checkerboard,2) - but now, I have to implement it in a Mathematica neural network. Is there a way to accomplish such a transformation, only using consecutive ArrayReshapes and Transposes (or any other array manipulation available to a neural net)?

Comment: Is this the same squeeze operation as SqueezeNet uses? If so, the squeeze defined in the WL implementation of Squeezenet may be what you need; https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/SqueezeNet-V1.1-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using a convolution layer with fixed weights

```
data = List@
   ArrayFlatten[
    Partition[Partition[#, 2] & /@ Partition[Range[16], 4], 2]];
MatrixForm@First@data
```

[image]

```
conv = ConvolutionLayer[4, {2, 2}, "Input" -> {1, 4, 4}, 
  "Stride" -> 2, 
  "Weights" -> {{{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}}, {{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {1, 
       0}}}, {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}}}, "Biases" -> None]

MatrixForm /@ conv[{data}]
```

[image]